# Joining words together with a comma, and "and"

Tags: python, list

I'm working through '[Automate the Boring Stuff with Python](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/)'. I can't figure out how to remove the final output comma from the program below. The goal is to keep prompting the user to input values, which are then printed out in a list, with "and" inserted before the end. The output should look something like this:

```
apples, bananas, tofu, and cats
```

Mine looks like this:

```
apples, bananas, tofu, and cats,
```

That last comma is driving me NUTS.

```
def lister():
    listed = []
    while True:
        print('type what you want to be listed or type nothing to exit')
        inputted = input()
        if inputted == '':
            break
        else:
            listed.append(inputted+',')
    listed.insert(-1, 'and')
    for i in listed:
        print(i, end=' ')
lister()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join list in Python but make the last separator different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30083949/how-to-join-list-in-python-but-make-the-last-separator-different)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can avoid adding commas to each string in the list by deferring the formatting to print time. Join all the items excluding the last on `', '`, then use formatting to insert the joined string with the last item conjuncted by `and`:

```
listed.append(inputed)
...
print('{}, and {}'.format(', '.join(listed[:-1]), listed[-1]))
```

---

Demo:

```
>>> listed = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> print('{}, and {}'.format(', '.join(listed[:-1]), listed[-1]))
a, b, c, and d
```

Comment: Improvement suggestion: `str.format` is no longer recommended, and 3.6 added support for a new inline formatting syntax that makes the code even more readable if you want to use a formatting approach: `f"{', '.join(listed[:-1])}, and {listed[-1]}"`. However, I would say no formatting at all is the most readable: `', '.join(listed[:-1]) + ", and" + listed[-1]`

Comment: @gntskn Is `str.format` really "no longer recommended"? I would argue that the format string itself is easier to read as is, could be extracted to a `fmt` variable, etc. I'm sure there are use cases for `f"..."` strings, especially when just pasting local variables into a format string, but to say that `str.format` is "no longer recommended" at all seems a bit overzealous.

Comment: @ZacCrites You know what, you're right; I was thinking of the `%` operator. This is what I get for posting from my phone right before midnight :p

Comment: @gntskn Also note that *f-strings* are not available in Python versions < 3.6

Comment: This code doesn't handle the list having less than 3 items.

Answer (score 21):

The accepted answer is good, but it might be better to move this functionality into a separate function that takes a list, and also handle the edge cases of 0, 1, or 2 items in the list:

```
def oxfordcomma(listed):
    if len(listed) == 0:
        return ''
    if len(listed) == 1:
        return listed[0]
    if len(listed) == 2:
        return listed[0] + ' and ' + listed[1]
    return ', '.join(listed[:-1]) + ', and ' + listed[-1]
```

Test cases:

```
>>> oxfordcomma([])
''
>>> oxfordcomma(['apples'])
'apples'
>>> oxfordcomma(['apples', 'pears'])
'apples and pears'
>>> oxfordcomma(['apples', 'pears', 'grapes'])
'apples, pears, and grapes'
```

Comment: Good modularization. For the general case I think I prefer passing the list to join with the last item having `and ` prefixed, so the comma gets added by `join` along with the rest of them: `', '.join(listed[:-1] + [f'and {listed[-1]}'])`... but that seems like a simple aesthetic choice.

Answer (score 8):

This will remove the comma from the last word.

```
listed[-1] = listed[-1][:-1]
```

The way it works is `listed[-1]` gets the last value from the list. We use `=` to assign this value to `listed[-1][:-1]`, which is a slice of the last word from the list with everything before the last character.

Implemented as shown below:

```
def lister():
    listed = []
    while True:
        print('type what you want to be listed or type nothing to exit')
        inputted = input()
        if inputted == '':
            break
        else:
            listed.append(inputted+',')
    listed.insert(-1, 'and')
    listed[-1] = listed[-1][:-1]
    for i in listed:
        print(i, end=' ')
lister()
```

Comment: So this works like a charm and thank you for the answer but i do not understand what this (listed[-1] = listed[-1][:-1]) does

Comment: @Admin_Who I added an explanation to the answer for you.

Answer (score 4):

Modifying your code a little bit...

```
def lister():
    listed = []
    while True:
        print('type what you want to be listed or type nothing to exit')
        inputted = input()
        if inputted == '':
            break
        else:
            listed.append(inputted) # removed the comma here

    print(', '.join(listed[:-2]) + ' and ' + listed[-1])  #using the join operator, and appending and xxx at the end
lister()
```

Comment: You need more: OP has already inserted commas into the individual strings.

Comment: This will add a comma behind the ``and``.

Answer (score 3):

```
listed[-1] = listed[-1][:-1]
```

This will truncate the final character of the final string in `listed`.

Answer (score 3):

I would do it using an f-string (a [formatted string literal](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), available in Python 3.6+):

```
def grammatically_join(words, oxford_comma=False):
    if len(words) == 0:
        return ""
    if len(words) == 1:
        return listed[0]
    if len(words) == 2:
        return f"{listed[0]} and {listed[1]}"
    return f'{", ".join(words[:-1])}{"," if oxford_comma else ""} and {words[-1]}'
```

If you don't need the [Oxford comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxford_comma), then you can simplify the code and remove the extra edge case for `len(words) == 2`:

```
def grammatically_join(words):
    if len(words) == 0:
        return ""
    if len(words) == 1:
        return listed[0]
    return f'{", ".join(words[:-1])} and {words[-1]}'
```

Answer (score 2):

Lots of ways to do it, but how about this?

```
# listed[-1] is the last element of the list
# rstrip removes matching characters from the end of the string
listed[-1] = listed[-1].rstrip(',')
listed.insert(-1, 'and')
for i in listed:
    print(i, end=' ')
```

You'll still be printing a space at the end of the line, but I guess you won't see it and thus won't care. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're okay with a comma if there are only two items, this is fairly compact:

```
def commaize(items):
    return ', and'.join(', '.join(items).rsplit(',', 1))
```

Which behaves like this:

```
>>> commaize([])
''
>>> commaize(['apples'])
'apples'
>>> commaize(['apples', 'bananas'])
'apples, and bananas'
>>> commaize(['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats'])
'apples, bananas, tofu, and cats'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by using inflect package and p.join()

```
import inflect
p = inflect.engine()
nameList = []
while True:
    try:
        names = input("Name: ")
        nameList.append(names)

    except EOFError:
        break


lastStr = p.join(nameList , ",")
print("\r", lastStr)
```